# Spectacular as an adjective

Tags: adjectives

Is it true that it is wrong to write 'a spectacular day'? I was told that spectacular can only be used together with 'event'. Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: I'd think that spectacular should apply to anything that may be observed or seen. A spectacular day seems perfectly legitimate to me. In fact, this is directly quoted from the online dictionary: **Spectacular ~ beautiful in a dramatic and eye-catching way.
"spectacular mountain scenery"**. So it seems unreasonable to prohibit anyone from applying the word to the description of a *day*.

Comment: If you look in any reasonable dictionary, there will be examples of sentences which includ the word 'spectacular'. The first I looked in had it premodifying two other nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first answer I made on this site I was chided for not giving a source of reference. Apparently that is an arbitrary standard. **Spectacular**, comes from  **spectacle** 1: something exhibited to view as unusual, notable, or entertaining; especially : an eye-catching or dramatic public display. Making **Spectacular:** of, relating to, or being a spectacle : striking, sensational a spectacular display of fireworks. www.merriam-webster.com It can also be applied to any feeling, or moment that is extraordinary. "Did you have a good day? Yes. It was spectacular!"

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with restrictions like "this adjective can only be used with this set of nouns".

Either way, you could describe a "day" as an "event".

Spectacular means outstanding in a visual way, so in that sense it "should only be used with" things for how they are seen, so would not be used to describe a song.

But language is about creativity and ingenuity. Songs can be visualized too.

Answer (score 0):

As an adjective, spectacular can modify any noun where it makes sense--art, music, fashion, social events, auctions of precious objects, etc., can be spectacular, as well as sports contests, highway crashes, natural disasters, and so forth.

As a noun, a spectacular is an event, e.g., a musical show, that is designed to be spectacular.